# Code doesn't run after msgbox web automation

Tags: excel, vba

Please, I got that macro to pick a lot of information from a website that one needs to use a digital certificate to access.

I start the macro and stop it using a msgbox. After the logon, the user clicks `ok` in msgbox and the code should to continue running. Now, I changed to office 2016 and it stoped, like it lost the browser connection after click the msgbox.

Why does the code stop in Office 2016?

**Code:**

```
Set appIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With appIE
    .navigate URL
    .Visible = True
End With

MsgBox "Please, logon and ok."

Do While appIE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop

Set doc = appIE.document
Set UserN = doc.getElementsByName("nrCE")
If Not UserN Is Nothing Then
    UserN(0).Value = ncem
End If
```

Comment: Is there an error message you are seeing?

Comment: No. It stops. I think that "excel 2016" do not acept ".readyState".